# Please remove Community Wiki from "What makes a photo good?" question

Tags: support, community-wiki

[What makes a photo a good photo?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2296/what-makes-a-photo-a-good-photo) was marked community wiki long ago. I think we have conclusively shown that individual ownership of answers actually works much better, even (or perhaps especially) for answerable yet subjective questions.

In fact in this case there are several good answers, all which have only one author. Let's remove CW and give those authors (and the question-asker) proper credit (and maybe even attract more and even better answers.

Thank you!

Comment: This has no downvotes and no dissenting opinions so I'm doing it.

Comment: Thanks @AbbyT.Miller!